# How to insert Geonames to PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geonames

I'm a total beginner with PostGIS, and trying to create a database with the [geonames dataset](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt).

Their table has latitude and longtitude coordinates:

> latitude          : latitude in decimal degrees (wgs84)
>   longitude         : longitude in decimal degrees (wgs84)

Since the data is global and in WGS84, I've used  the  type:
`geography(point,4326)`, and inserted it using `ST_MakePoint(lat, long)`.

However, I get a lot of warnings:
`NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY`

Did I use the wrong type?

Comment: You likely failed to use the longitude value before the latitude in the constructor (in {x,y} order, as required), but you've left that key detail out of this question.  Please also edit to specify the exact software in use.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. Please post your comment as an answer, and I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to capture the actual procedure, so than an answer long enough to be worthwhile could be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is the #1 mistake that everyone learning PostGIS makes at least once, so don't feel silly)

The axis order for all coordinate data in PostGIS is (X Y) or (long lat).

Therefore the correct geometry constructor is `ST_MakePoint(long, lat)`.

You can also use [ST_FlipCoordinates](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html) to repair geometry/geography columns.